# Replace in a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have been converting code to use LINQ queries and have run into something I can't figure out (Super new to LINQ).

I have a custom object "maindata", which contains a list of strings for headers, it also contains a list of files (another custom object), and within that object is another list of strings for headers.

I essentially need to do 2 different things at different times

1) in maindata.file(1).headers.replace("x","y") (exact 100% match, and I know i cant .replace due to it being a list of strings)

2) in maindata.headers.replace("x","y"), as well as maindata.file(all).headers.replace("x","y") (again exact 100% matches)

I have done some basic boolean checks with LINQ but this is beyond what I've touched, any help would be appreciated.

Coding in vb.net

```
For I As Integer = 0 To MainData.HeaderName.Count - 1
    If MainData.HeaderName(I) = OldHeader Then
        MainData.HeaderName(I) = NewHeader
    End If
Next
For I As Integer = 0 To MainData.Files.Count - 1
    For J As Integer = 0 To MainData.Files(I).CurrentHeaders.Count - 1
        If MainData.Files(I).CurrentHeaders(J) = OldHeader Then
            MainData.Files(I).CurrentHeaders(J) = NewHeader
        End If
    Next
Next

For I As Integer = 0 To SelectedFile.CurrentHeaders.Count - 1
    If SelectedFile.CurrentHeaders(I) = OldHeader Then
        SelectedFile.CurrentHeaders(I) = NewHeader
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Post what you've tried, but Linq is for _querying_, not _updating_.  You'll end up using a loop in the end anyways, so trying to shoehorn in Linq may just complicate things.  If you have it working with loops, there may be no need to convert to Linq.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid loops for performance. The program eventually is a data standardization tool, and the main data is the cumulative output of all the input files. The custom objects hold all the headers and information to join the data together later. A lot of lists, that can get rather large depending on the incoming data.

Comment: Linq _IS_ loops, just wrapped in a "cleaner" syntax.  Linq is not designed for _performance_ gains, but _coding efficiency_ gains.  _Changing data_ should be done in a loop.

Comment: The amount of nested looping is ridiculous, hence wanting to clean it up. Regardless of why, I want to try and do this in LINQ if possible.

Comment: So post what you have so far.  It may be possible to reduce the number of nested loops using Linq.

Comment: Please add it to your question so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Sorry about that. Had some issues getting it setup right. Also had to write this portion as a loop as the old code is irrelevant and drastically different.

Comment: I don't see how LINQ would result in "cleaner" code here.  However, changing your `For I As Integer...` loops to `For Each x In` loops....

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not going to help here for one reason.  You are modifying the values in the collections.  If they were collections of *reference types* that you wanted to update a property of, then you could loop over them and update the property, but since they're collections of values types then you *have* to update with a `For` loop.

The *only* place where I can see a *very minor* improvement is by making one `For` loop a `For Each` loop:

```
For Each file in MainData.Files
    For J As Integer = 0 To file.CurrentHeaders.Count - 1
        If file.CurrentHeaders(J) = OldHeader Then
            file.CurrentHeaders(J) = NewHeader
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I typically stick to For loops over For Each, because I have a lot of linked data, and any changes later I might need the value of my location. (I have quite a few single loops i could make for each loops.) Thanks for your help.